# Elastic Search Number of Document Views

Tags: algorithm, elasticsearch

I have a web app that is used to search and view documents in Elastic Search. 
The goal now is to maintain two values.
1. How many times the document was fetched in total (life time views)
2. How many times the document was fetched in last 30 days.

Achieving the first is somewhat possible, but the second one seems to be a very hard problem.
The two values need to be part of the document as they will be used for sorting the results.

What is the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

To maintain expiring data like that you will need to store each view with its timestamp. I suppose you could store them in an array in the ES document, but you're asking for trouble doing it like that, as the update operation that you'd need to call every time the document is viewed will have to delete and recreate the document (that's how ES does updates), and if two views happen at the same time it will be difficult to make sure they both get stored.

There are two ways to store the views, and make use of them in the query:

1. Put them in a separate store (could be a different index in ES if you like), and run a cron job or similar every day to update every item in the main index with the number of views from the last thirty days in the view store. Even with a lot of data it should be possible to make this quite efficient, depending on your choice of store for views.
2. Use the ElasticSearch [parent/child datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html) to store views in the same index as the main documents, as children. I'm not sure that I'd particularly recommend this approach, but I think it should be possible with aggregations to write a query that sorts primary documents by the number of children (filtered by date). It might be quite slow though.

I doubt there is any other way to do this with current versions of ES, because it doesn't support joining across indices. Either the data must be aggregated in advance onto the document, or it has to be available in the same index.